# How to get GPS updates in doze mode 8.0 Oreo devices?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location, android-gps, android-doze

- I'm using a foreground service to fetch GPS with an interval of 30 seconds and save it in DB. I use alarm manager to post GPS logs every 15 minutes from DB,this seems to work even in doze mode with **setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()** but GPS passively stops working in doze hence DB is empty in duration of doze mode

> > I've tried to whitelist the app which uses a manifest permission *ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS* which violets [google play policies](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases)  while app publish. Also Samsung devices J6 which I'm developing for has unmonitored apps option in settings which seem similar to app whitelisting which is not handled.
>
> I have read about doze mode and it's maintenance windows for deferred work but I want to actively get GPS even if device goes to sleep and stationary

### How to achieve this fine kettle of fish?

Comment: `Location services may be disabled when the screen is off.`. Google may kill Android in decade or so. Check [more](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power)

Comment: @MD That is what I don't want..Is there a way to keep it alive?

Comment: Please ask to Google for this.